# How to force JVM 64-bit to use more than 4GB for the heap?

Tags: parameters, jvm, heap-memory

This is quite puzzling, 64-bit OS, 64-bit JDK, 16GB of RAM, and I am unable to use more than 4GB for the heap. Here is how I start the program (my program is in Scala, but it is based on JVM):

```
/usr/lib64/jvm/java/bin/java -d64 -Xms512m -Xmx10g ...jars go on
```

And when I read the total memory within my program (`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`)... the reading is "4242MB".

**QUESTION** -- how to force JVM to use the amount memory I already provided (10 GB)?

`java -version` says:

```
java version "1.6.0_29"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode)
```

### Update 1

`maxMemory` returns "9102MB", so now there is the question where the difference went (both 1GB and 5GB), and how to use all maximum memory (my program crashes, because it requires 2 chunks of ~3GB, and 4GB in total is not enough).

### Update 2

Now, I put all the readings before and after my allocation, and surprise, surprise, first reading of total memory was 4GB, the second too, but third one peaked to 8GB. I am glad, total memory can increase all of the sudden, because it solves my problem, but I don't understand it.

Comment: What does maxMemory() return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM will try to use all of the `10g` only when it really needs it. Since you have specified `-Xmx10g`, this is the max memory that it will try to use. Is the program unable to allocate more than 4g when it needs it?

And check the output of

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()
```

Comment: The problem is, I also check the `freeMemory` (for `max` see the update), and when I try allocate second chunk, which would fit into 10GB, but not into 4GB, my program crashes with exception.